# After f32 update on Acer Laptop: built-in keyboard not working

Tags: linux, keyboard, fedora, gnome, wayland

**Update:**
I tried several distros and finally installed the [Fedora Compiz Mate Desktop](https://spins.fedoraproject.org/mate-compiz/). It works fine with built-in-Keyboard working. But running `sudo dnf update` installed me a newer kernel, where I have the same issures. I roughly checked some journal-entrys, but it looks quite the same.
Actual workaround: I manually select the older kernel and the built-in-keyboard is working.
In grub-menu

- the newer kernel, built in keyboard **not working**: Fedora (5.7.14-200.fc32x86_64) 32 (thrirty-two)
- the older kernel, built in keyboard **working**: Fedora (5.6.6-300.fc32x86_64) 32 (thrirty-two)

I'd like to follow @rickhg12hs suggest and

- downgrade the older kernel

or

- find way that grub will take the older kernel for default.

How can I do this?

Additionally I'm glad to have any suggestions, that further kernel-updates will be prevented, what do you think of `sudo dnf update --exclude=kernel*` (found [here](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/t/howto-prevent-kernel-updates/3001))

Looking forward for your help!

---

Cross posted here: https://ask.fedoraproject.org/t/after-f32-update-on-acer-laptop-built-in-keyboard-not-working/8359
Hi there!
I’m quite new to Fedora and asking for your help with a keyboard issue.

Recently I updated my laptop from fedora 31 to fedora 32. When I tried to type my password on lockscreen I realized, that the build-in keyboard of my laptop isn’t working. Log in with external USB-Keyboard worked. [I already know that my touchpad is broken for some reason].

GNOME-Version 3.36.3., Fedora 32, Wayland, up to date

My Laptop: Acer Aspire E5-511-P7AT; Intel® Pentium® CPU N3530 @ 2.16GHz × 4; Intel® HD Graphics (BYT)

Update everything with `sudo dnf update` hasn’t solved the problem.

The Keyboard is working in BIOS. Therefore I assume, that the problem might be connected with `libinput`.
Terminal Output (selection):

```
sudo libinput list-devices
Device: Logitech USB Keyboard
Kernel: /dev/input/event6
Group: 6
Seat: seat0, default
Capabilities: keyboard
Tap-to-click: n/a
Tap-and-drag: n/a
Tap drag lock: n/a
Left-handed: n/a
Nat.scrolling: n/a
Middle emulation: n/a
Calibration: n/a
Scroll methods: none
Click methods: none
Disable-w-typing: n/a
Accel profiles: n/a
Rotation: n/a

Device: Logitech USB Keyboard Consumer Control
Kernel: /dev/input/event7
Group: 6
Seat: seat0, default
Capabilities: keyboard
Tap-to-click: n/a
Tap-and-drag: n/a
Tap drag lock: n/a
Left-handed: n/a
Nat.scrolling: n/a
Middle emulation: n/a
Calibration: n/a
Scroll methods: none
Click methods: none
Disable-w-typing: n/a
Accel profiles: n/a
Rotation: n/a

Device: Logitech USB Keyboard System Control
Kernel: /dev/input/event14
Group: 6
Seat: seat0, default
Capabilities: keyboard
Tap-to-click: n/a
Tap-and-drag: n/a
Tap drag lock: n/a
Left-handed: n/a
Nat.scrolling: n/a
Middle emulation: n/a
Calibration: n/a
Scroll methods: none
Click methods: none
Disable-w-typing: n/a
Accel profiles: n/a
Rotation: n/a

Device: Logitech USB Optical Mouse
Kernel: /dev/input/event5
Group: 7
Seat: seat0, default
Capabilities: pointer
Tap-to-click: n/a
Tap-and-drag: n/a
Tap drag lock: n/a
Left-handed: disabled
Nat.scrolling: disabled
Middle emulation: disabled
Calibration: n/a
Scroll methods: button
Click methods: none
Disable-w-typing: n/a
Accel profiles: flat *adaptive
Rotation: n/a

Device: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard
Kernel: /dev/input/event4
Group: 10
Seat: seat0, default
Capabilities: keyboard
Tap-to-click: n/a
Tap-and-drag: n/a
Tap drag lock: n/a
Left-handed: n/a
Nat.scrolling: n/a
Middle emulation: n/a
Calibration: n/a
Scroll methods: none
Click methods: none
Disable-w-typing: n/a
Accel profiles: n/a
Rotation: n/a

Device: Acer WMI hotkeys
Kernel: /dev/input/event12
Group: 11
Seat: seat0, default
Capabilities: keyboard
Tap-to-click: n/a
Tap-and-drag: n/a
Tap drag lock: n/a
Left-handed: n/a
Nat.scrolling: n/a
Middle emulation: n/a
Calibration: n/a
Scroll methods: none
Click methods: none
Disable-w-typing: n/a
Accel profiles: n/a
Rotation: n/a
```

`AT Translated Set 2 keyboard` seems to be the built-in keyboard. Running `sudo libinput debug-events` in terminal gives:

```
-event3 DEVICE_ADDED Power Button seat0 default group1 cap:k
-event8 DEVICE_ADDED Video Bus seat0 default group2 cap:k
-event1 DEVICE_ADDED Power Button seat0 default group3 cap:k
-event0 DEVICE_ADDED Lid Switch seat0 default group4 cap:S
-event2 DEVICE_ADDED Sleep Button seat0 default group5 cap:k
-event6 DEVICE_ADDED Logitech USB Keyboard seat0 default group6 cap:k
-event7 DEVICE_ADDED Logitech USB Keyboard Consumer Control seat0 default group6 cap:k
-event14 DEVICE_ADDED Logitech USB Keyboard System Control seat0 default group6 cap:k
-event5 DEVICE_ADDED Logitech USB Optical Mouse seat0 default group7 cap:p left scroll-nat scroll-button
-event13 DEVICE_ADDED HD WebCam: HD WebCam seat0 default group8 cap:k
-event9 DEVICE_ADDED Intel Virtual Button driver seat0 default group9 cap:kS
event9 SWITCH_TOGGLE +0.000s switch tablet-mode state 1
-event4 DEVICE_ADDED AT Translated Set 2 keyboard seat0 default group10 cap:k
-event12 DEVICE_ADDED Acer WMI hotkeys seat0 default group11 cap:k
-event5 POINTER_MOTION +0.000s -1.62/ 0.00 ( -5.00/ +0.00)
```

Pressing any key on the built-in keyboard give no respond in `libinput debug-events`, exept for some FN-keys (event4).

What can I do now to get this built-in keyboard to work?
I’m looking forward for your help.

Best regards

smallfire

Comment: Anything interesting in`journalctl -k -g 'input:'`?

Comment: Hi @rickhg12hs and thanks for your answer! `journalctl -k -g 'input:'` gives `kernel: input: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard as /devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input4`, but in `journalctl -k` i found: `kernel: i8042: PNP: PS/2 Controller [PNP0303:PS2K] at 0x60,0x64 irq 1` and
`kernel: i8042: PNP: PS/2 appears to have AUX port disabled, if this is incorrect please boot with i8042.nopnp` which led me with google to a similar problem (touchpad isnt working at my laptop, too): [https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-1086512-start-0.html]

Comment: following [https://askubuntu.com/questions/525629/touchpad-is-not-recognized] I changed in `etc/default/grub` from `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="resume=/dev/mapper/fedora_localhost--live-swap rd.lvm.lv=fedora_localhost-live/root rd.lvm.lv=fedora_localhost-live/swap rhgb quiet"` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="resume=/dev/mapper/fedora_localhost--live-swap rd.lvm.lv=fedora_localhost-live/root rd.lvm.lv=fedora_localhost-live/swap rhgb quiet i8042.reset i8042.nomux i8042.nopnp i8042.noloop"` than: `sudo grub2-mkconfig -o "$(readlink -e /etc/grub2.conf)"`

Comment: last command following [https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/152222/equivalent-of-update-grub-for-rhel-fedora-centos-systems]. Reboot, but keyboard and touchpad still don't work. `sudo libinput list-devices` shows now 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad` (I'm quite sure it was not before. 'journalctl -k -g 'input:'' nothing new, but I found with `journalctl -k -g 'i8042'` the following: `kernel: i8042: PNP detection disabled` and no more the former `PNP: PS/2 appears to have AUX ...` message. That looks like that the change in GRUB was successfull -- but keyboard and touchpad still don't working.

Comment: Hi @smallfire.  It's better if you provide new information by editing your original question and including it there.  It will make it a bit easier for future readers.  It is curious that PNP doesn't seem to work with the AUX port.  My laptop says, `kernel: i8042: PNP: PS/2 Controller [PNP0303:PS2K,PNP0f03:PS2M] at 0x60,0x64 irq 1,12` and later `kernel: serio: i8042 AUX port at 0x60,0x64 irq 12`.

Comment: I'm wondering if you installed and booted into a previous version of the kernel if it might work.  I.e., still F32 but downgrade the kernel version.

Comment: Hi @rickhg12hs thank your suggestions. It really has something to do with the kernel. Can you please help me in my questions I gave now in the orginal question? That would be very kind!

Comment: Hi @smallfire.  It's important that each StackExchange question be targeted to a single issue really.  Think of StackExchange as an encyclopedia that is indexed by the question titles and tags.  Also think about how a question could be answered.  The answers need to target a single issue also.